# Why is this XSLT loop iterating twice?

Tags: xslt

I have the following XSLT snippet:

```
                <xsl:for-each
                    select="distinct-values(/summary/results[@count eq $currentResult]/simulator/host/tps)">


                    <th>
                        <small>
                            TPS Avg

                            <br></br>
                        </small>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <small>
                            TPS 95th%tile

                            <br></br>
                        </small>
                    </th>

                </xsl:for-each>
```

Since, I have used distinct-values I would expect this to iterate once through the loop, but it iterates twice. Twice makes no sense even if distinct-values was not working properly, as there are **3** distinct instances of 'tps' in the XML document. Any ideas appreciated...

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete samples of XML input and XSLT that allow us to easily reproduce the problem. Showing us a snippet of XSLT without  any input allowing us to see which values that snippet professes does not allow us to explain what happens.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have enough information. I would appreciate your comments on the answer, if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

`distinct-values` on a node:

```
distinct-values(/summary/results[@count eq $currentResult]/simulator/host/tps
```

is different to `distinct-values` on an atomic value:

```
distinct-values(/summary/results[@count eq $currentResult]/simulator/host/tps/avg/text()
```

When you use a node, the children of that node have to be identical in order for it to extract one entry from the XML tree.

Consider the following:

```
         <tps>
           <avg>8.99</avg>
           <percentile>11.0</percentile>
        </tps>

        <tps>
           <avg>8.99</avg>
           <percentile>11.0</percentile>
        </tps>

        <tps>
           <avg>8.99</avg>
           <percentile>10.0</percentile>
        </tps>
```

You might think that `select-distinct` will only return one entry for `<tps>` here but it considers children in this case. In the case above there are **2** distinct nodes: avg and percentile are identical in two of the nodes. This is why it looped over the for-each twice.

Comment: No, that explanation has various misconceptions, first of all you write `select-distinct` as if it were some language feature although there is no such feature. As for `distinct-values`, which is the language feature you use, both your examples `distinct-values(/summary/results[@count eq $currentResult]/simulator/host/tps)` and `distinct-values(/summary/results[@count eq $currentResult]/simulator/host/tps/avg/text())` call the `distinct-values` function on a sequence of nodes, the first one on a sequence of `tps` elements, the second on a sequence of text nodes.

Comment: oops sorry - i meant to use distinct-values in all cases

Comment: ok, i see what you mean - how do i have it so that it returns only one value when it has children which make it non unique? I only want one tps returned in other words when there are three 'tps' nodes in the xml document.

Comment: I am still not sure what you are after. If you want to eliminate duplicates based on the element name and not on the element value then you need `distinct-values(/summary/results[@count eq $currentResult]/simulator/host/tps/node-name(.))`. But somehow that would only make sense if your path selected something with `*` or other ways that could result in elements with different names.

Comment: `distinct-values(/summary/results[@count eq $currentResult]/simulator/host/tps/node-name(.))` is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!